# How is snapshotChanges aware of changes?

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2, firefox-developer-tools

I have installed `@angular/fire` (latest version 5) dependency.

```
  getCustomersList() {
    this.customerService.getCustomersList().snapshotChanges().pipe(
      map(changes =>
        changes.map(c =>
          ({ key: c.payload.doc.id, ...c.payload.doc.data() })
        )
      )
    ).subscribe(customers => {
      this.customers = customers;
    });
```

If I open with `F12` the Network tab of Firefox, I don't see any network activity, even if I "magically" receive a change (from another browser instance, for example). But I assume that the app client (living in the browser) is polling periodically the remote db: is it confirmed somehow?
Which is the mechanism - under the covers - by which it can subscribe changes done elsewhere? Why can't I visualize it in the browser developer tools? Since `@angular/fire` is open source on [github](https://github.com/angular/angularfire), can someone point me to the relevant part of the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I was wrong, now I can see (screenshot below) the requests coming approx one per minute from the [Zone.js](https://github.com/angular/angular/tree/master/packages/zone.js/) scheduler.

Indeed, the first paragraph of [this article](https://medium.com/better-programming/zone-js-for-angular-devs-573d89bbb890) simply answers my question

> Angular introduced Zone.js to handle change detection. This allows
>   Angular to decide when the UI has to be refreshed. Usually, you don’t
>   have to care about any of this, because Zone.js just works.

[image]

Comment: you should read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18638917/firebase-callbacks-whats-the-underlying-trigger

Comment: @Giulio You're correct: Cloud Firestore does not use Web Sockets for its transport, but instead relies on multiplexed HTTP/2 calls. It's Firebase Realtime Database (which was still just called "Firebase" back when Kato answer that question in **2013**) that uses Web Sockets.